# System.Web.Http.Description error in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting an error when i am coding

```
 [Description("A+")]           /// error like **"The type or Namespace name "Description" counld not be found(Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
    APositive,
```

I have a reference to System.Web.Http and a using System.Web.Http.Description. Then I get the above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DescriptionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) belongs to the `System.ComponentModel` namespace. That's what you need to add as `using`.